# SpringBoot Post works locally but in dev region fails with 415 "Content type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a springboot Rest service with below request mapping.I need the request and response in XML. When I test "POST" works locally and response received in XML format but in Dev region same request fails with status 415?any thoughts\help?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE }, headers = "Accept=application/xml")
```

Response I get from Dev region

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-23T14:49:29.293+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/get"
}
```

Comment: Could you check what content-type header is being passed from your browser?

Comment: I tested thru postman and Soapui..both cases it works locally..but when I point to Dev link it fails with 415

Comment: Because you might have added content-type in postman yourself, and if you don't add content-type in your request, The browser adds a default for you. Are you testing your dev environment also with postman?

Comment: yes I tested dev too with postman..

Comment: Something is adding charset to your request, try checking if you have any load balancers or something which might be changing your content-type header

Comment: Adding jackson-dataformat-xml as dependency solved the issue.Thanks @SagarAhuja for looking into it.

Answer (score -1):

Added below Gradle dependency - 
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.10.0'